# Proof that merging 2 sets results in another

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Consider those 2 sets:

$$\mathbb{P} = \{2n \vert n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}\}$$
$$\mathbb{O} = \{2n + 1 \vert n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}\}$$

Is there any way to prove that

$$\mathbb{P} \cup \mathbb{O} = \mathbb{N}_{0}$$

What I thought of is this:

$$\mathbb{P} = \mathbb{N}_{0} \setminus \mathbb{O} \Rightarrow (\mathbb{N}_{0} \setminus \mathbb{O}) \cup \mathbb{O} = \mathbb{N}_{0} = \mathbb{N}_{0}$$

But that is hardly a proof I think. Also, my proof would fail for any other non-intuitive set combination.

So, what would be a better proof? For context, I'm still in high school.

Comment: You essentially need to show that every number is either even or odd.  You'll need the well-ordering principle to do that.

Comment: You can use induction on $n$. Prove that $0\in\mathbb P\cup\mathbb O$ and secondly that $n\in\mathbb P\cup\mathbb O$ implies $n+1\in\mathbb P\cup\mathbb O$

Comment: It's not actually true since $1\not\in \mathbb{P} \cup \mathbb{O}$ but $1\in\Bbb N$

Comment: @vrugtehagel I see, for me $0 \in \mathbb{N}$. I'll clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first note that all numbers in $\Bbb P$ are in $\Bbb N_0$ and all numbers in $\Bbb O$ are in $\Bbb N_0$, so $\Bbb P\subseteq\Bbb N_0$ and $\Bbb O\subseteq\Bbb N_0$.

Second, we need to show that if $n\in\Bbb N_0$, then either $n\in\Bbb P$ or $n\in\Bbb O$ (or both). Assume this is not the case. That means, we can find an $n$ such that we cannot write $n=2k+1$ or $n=2k$ for any (nonnegative) integer $k$. Then we look at

$$S_n=\{n-2k\mid k\in\Bbb N_0, n-2k\in\Bbb N_0\}$$

This is a subset of $\Bbb N_0$, and thus it contains a smallest element (note: there is an element, since $n-2\cdot 0=n\in\Bbb N_0$). Now call the smallest element $s$. If $s=0$, then we know there exists a $k\in \Bbb N_0$ with $n-2k=0$ or $n=2k$, and this is impossible. If $s=1$, then we can find a $k$ with $n-2k=1$, or $n=2k+1$. Also impossible. Thus, $s\geq 2$, which means $s-2\in\Bbb N_0$. Since $s\in S_n$, we know there exists a $k\in\Bbb N_0$ with $s=n-2k$ (and $s\in\Bbb N_0$). But then we can find an $l=k+1$ with $s-2=n-2l$ and $s-2\in\Bbb N_0$ (and $l\in\Bbb N_0$), so this means $s-2\in S_n$! Contradiction, because $s$ was the smallest element in $S_n$. Thus, our initial assumption is false, and so we conclude the following

> If $n\in\Bbb P$ or $n\in\Bbb O$, then $n\in\Bbb N_0$. Furthermore, if $n\in\Bbb N_0$, then either $n\in\Bbb P$ or $n\in\Bbb O$ (or both).

From which we conclude $\Bbb P\cup\Bbb O=\Bbb N_0$.

Comment: Why is it impossible to find a $k$ with $s=0$ for $n = 2k$? Isn't then $k = 0 \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$?

Comment: Yes, but you assume that there is no $k$ with $n=2k+1$ or $n=2k$. That's what you're creating the contradiction from

Comment: Makes sense :) Also, how did you come up with the $S_n$? Is it linked to something or does the same argument hold with any subset of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Usually you do things this way when you need to use the well-ordering principle (every nonempty subset of $\Bbb N$ has a smallest element). You want to make a nonempty set, and use the fact that it has a smallest to prove something (usually by assuming that the smallest element is not the thing you want it to be, $0$ or $1$ in this case, and then proving by contradiction).